# Local theme changes upload on server but theme changes not showing

Tags: theme-development, themes

i created website in local using word press theme, then uploaded on server but in server database have table like **wp_2xxfpfb5qn_options** and local have tables like "doc_options" so its not taking value from proper table, hence my theme not showing as i did changes in local theme. so what i have do for it?

Now, it's showing please check this link
[Site](http://clinic2.cruxbytes.com)

Comment: Sounds like you may either be running into caching issues, or you haven't actually activated the correct theme. In your remote server, head over to appearance > themes and make sure you've chosen the customized theme. As Ket has already answered, you should also use a migration plugin, not just upload raw files and try to import the data directly. WP uses a lot of serialized data, especially when it comes to themes, so search and replace isn't enough.

Answer (score 0):

Just upload your theme and WordPress using migration plugin also in some cases widget option destroy so better to upload WordPress using migration plugin.

Comment: i have all changes in server files but its not showing on browser

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution, go to your wp-config.php in that find $table_prefix variable. server have bydefault variable like $table_prefix  = 'wp_2xxn5nq_' it can be any thing on server just put your prefix in that variable;